# Can a mutable object in Redux store that is only mutated outside of Redux cause unexpected side effects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutability

Given this situation:

- There is a mutable object inside the Redux store
- Reducers do not mutate the object; all reducers are still pure functions with no side effects
- The mutable object is sometimes mutated **outside** of Redux, for example, by calling methods on the object itself

My question is, is this "safe" to do, or could there be problematic side effects, and if so what and why? In particular, can this impact performance, can it mess with the way Redux re-computes states, and can it mess with the rendering of React components if the object is passed down to them from the Redux store as a prop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should *never* mutate values that are in the Redux state, *ever***:

- https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-mutate-state

This can and will absolutely cause side effects, including the app potentially not rendering when it needs to.

If this "mutable object" you're referring to is some kind of class instance or similar, that also doesn't belong in the Redux store:

- https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions

**edit**

Per the discussion in comments, here's how I would suggest handling something like this WebGL context thing:

```js
const SomeParentComponent = () => {
  // Use Redux state to decide when we should show this
  const showWebGl = useSelector(state => state.ui.showWebGl);
  // Standard hooks "forceRender" implementation
  const [, forceRender] = useReducer(c => c + 1, 0)
  // Ref to hold the WebGL instance
  const webGlRef = useRef(null);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (showWebGl) {
      webGlRef.current = magicallyCreateWebGlInstance();
      forceRender(); // have to force a re-render to pass down the ref value
    }
    
    return () => {
      if (webGlRef.current) {
        magicallyDestroyWebGlInstance(webGlRef.current)
      }
    }

  }, [showWebGl])

  return (
    <MyWebGlContext.Provider value={webGlRef.current>
      <RestOfAppGoesHere />
    </MyWebGlContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

The WebGL instance itself doesn't belong in the store, because it's not *state*, and it's not serializable.  A Redux store shouldn't be used just as a way to hand around arbitrary values, especially if those values aren't plain JS data.

This way, the Redux state still drives whether the WebGL instance is being created, but the instance itself lives entirely in the UI layer and is still accessible to the rest of the component tree.

Comment: Ok thanks. In that case, where does a global class instance belong? I don't want to put it in Redux but I can't find any explanation of what is the correct way

Comment: For now I worked around by putting it on `window`, which is much better. Does not seem ideal at all but I can't figure out a better way, and I have looked pretty hard...

Comment: What is this "global class instance" actually used for?  One option would be to put it into a context provider near the root of the app so it can be accessed throughout the component tree.

Comment: It's an object to handle embedded WebGL. Root of app won't work in this case since I only want to load it in response to a specific action being dispatched. Doesn't need to be global as long as it can be instantiated in middleware and the same instance can be accessed from a component elsewhere to render. So basically just need some way of getting it from the middleware and the component. Normally would use mapStateToProps() but can't here since it can't be in the store.

Comment: Yeah, that really doesn't belong in Redux.  I'd still put it in a component, and pass down via context. If it only needs to exist part of the time, then have your Redux store have some kind of `showWebGlThingy: true` flag that gets set when that action is dispatched, and create and pass down the WebGL instance in a parent component once that value is true.

Comment: Should I create a new question with those details? Since it's getting off topic - this question was more specific and I was hoping to get more of the "why" answered, but that doesn't really matter outside of satisfying my curiosity. I was hoping better understanding here could help me think of a workaround too. I wondered if putting pointer there would work, since pointers can be immutable, but tbh that seems significantly worse than just putting it on the window lol

Comment: Thanks @markerikson - That's my current solution, to put some flags in Redux for it, but have the actual instance in window. If I post this as its own question, would you answer with example of what you mean by "put it in a component" - do you mean handle it all within the rendering component, using hooks logic? I'd considered if I can handle this entirely within the component's logic, but I'm afraid I need some help understanding what's possible there.